# Prove the following formula is a contradiction: (~(A --> B)) ^ (B V ~ A)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[image]

I have worked with this truth table now - is everything correct or, do I miss something?

Comment: Yup  everything is correct.

Comment: A friendly reminder, on this site we use MathJax and $\LaTeX$ for typing mathematics.  [Visit this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to do so.  Instead of typing (~(A --> B)) ^ (B V ~ A), you could make it look much cleaner as $(\neg (A\rightarrow B))\wedge (B\vee \neg A)$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everything looks fine. ${}$